# Conversion from Cartesian to polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have some difficulty with converting this implicit, Cartesian function into polar form:
$\left(y^2+x^2\right)^2=2\left(x^2-y^2\right)$

I know that, in order to attempt to convert it, I need to use $x=r\cos\left(\theta\right)$ and $y=r\sin\left(\theta\right)$ and $x^2+y^2=r
^2;$  however, when I try applying these substitutions it seems like the $r$ cancels out and I'm left with a function independent of $r$.

Am I missing anything important? Thank you for the answers in advance!

Comment: No, $r$ doesn't cancel out, review your exponents.

Comment: ahh allright i see what i did, i was trying to solve $x^2+y^2=2(x^2-y^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\rho^4=2\rho^2\cos2\theta$$

is also

$$\rho=\sqrt{2\cos2\theta},$$

which is a lemniscate.